# Has Facebook banned apps for posting likes and comments?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post comments on Facebook using a valid access token generated by an app called HTC Sence but I get this error:
"Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated because the user has changed the password." when I never changed the password." and some other times i get: "It seems that you been using this feature too fast and You've been blocked from using it"

I use this token because it never expires and it helps me to post comments or reply to comments while I'm away, after I try to post a comment the token expires automatically. Has Facebook banned HTC Sense and other apps from performing these actions? I don't believe I'm doing anything wrong because I've been doing that since a couple of months ago using the Facebook graph API and nothing have gone wrong until now. Thank you

Comment: i hope so. only spammy/autoposted comments came from that htc sense app.

Comment: I do not believe this is a programming question. Perhaps you should go to the developer of the app for help?

Comment: _“I don't believe I'm doing anything wrong ”_ – by using access tokens for apps that don’t even belong to you? Of course that is wrong. If you want to interact with Facebook via the API, then the first step is that you create your own app. Or maybe make that the second one, after reading [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy). _“and it helps me to post comments or reply to comments while I'm away”_ - you are not allowed to autopost.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing this with IFTTT. It kills it if you post automatically too often.

Someone asked this: https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=730692276948913

Comment: I coded a PHP program to do that, but it seems like the tokens expire automatically every time I try to post a comment or like

Comment: autoposting is not allowed anyway ;)